# Angular websocket onMessage never fires with hapi nes

Tags: angularjs, hapi.js

I am using angular websocket library (https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket) on client side along with hapi nes (websocket) on server side.
I have a auth route where I am doing a publish on a channel that i defined earlier but the message never is received.
example

```
ServerSide:
file: server.js
server.subscription('/item/');

file:handlers.js
request.server.publish('/item/', { id: 5, status: 'complete' });

Client Side: Angular-websocket

myApp.factory('fac',['$websocket',function fac($websocket){

var dataStream = $websocket('ws://localhost:8000/item/');

dataStream.onOpen(function(message) {
  console.log("sockeet opeeeen");
  console.log(message);
});
dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
  console.log("xxxxxx");
  console.log(message);
  //collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
});
```

The onMessage never fires. Any idea what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: I'm removing the angular2 tag since this seems like the angular1 framework. Tell me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You may be assigning a function to an undefined object (onOpen).